# node/express anchor links not directing to the other HTML static page

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm building my first node.js/express.js project. This is what my [directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/492yq.png) looks like.

In my `index.html` and `favorites.html` files, I've included anchor tags to navigate between the two pages:

```html
<header class="menu">
  <a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
  <a href="favorites.html" class="favorite"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a>
</header>
```

When I run the server through node (localhost:3000), the nav links on `index.html` don't appear to work, nothing happens. However, when I go to localhost:3000/favorites.html, the nav links works and redirect me back to `index.html` and `favorites.html` itself.

In the `server.js` file, I've added express.static middleware to serve all the static files in the `public` folder following the express documentation and after reading different answers on here.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction of why the links on index.html may not be working? Thank you!

Comment: If clicking the links does nothing, but going directly to the URLs does, then the problem has nothing to do with Express and has something to do with your client side code. All else being equal, the problem is that there is nothing to click on (possibly you have some CSS to try to provide some background images to click on, but you aren't demonstrating the problem in your question (provide a [mcve]!) and the approach has major accessibility problems. If you want images to click on use an `<img>` with an `alt` attribute!

Answer (score -1):

Please use route as following:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + './public/index.html');
});

app.get("/favorites", function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + './public/favorites.html');
});
```

```html
<header class="menu">
  <a href="/"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
  <a href="/favorites" class="favorite"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a>
</header>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the `static` module? Why should they have to create an explicit route for every static page?

Comment: Could you share your full index.html file?

Comment: I tried this solution earlier too with no luck but have added the explicit routes just now to try again and the nav links on index.html still don't appear to redirect me to favorites.html. In response to @Quentin too, thank you for the suggestions. I swapped out the HTML icons to use images with alt instead and also commented out the css files to see if this is a problem linked to my CSS file but the anchor tags weirdly still don't seem to work

Comment: Sure, the index.html file is https://github.com/toowee-le/cocktails/blob/master/public/index.html